# nextPermutation using an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need help with finding the next Permutation of a given sequence in an ArrayList. One set of instructions are as follows:

Move from right to left until thecurrent number is less than the previous one.
Start at the right and find the first number greater than current.
Swap the numbers.
Reverse the order of the numbers to the right of the swapped value so that they are in increasing order.
When you go through the entire set and the current number is never less than the previous one, reset the permutation to the beginning (see resetPermutation) (which does Collections.sort(currentPermutation))

The beginning of the method is public ArrayList nextPermutation()

Here is what I have attempted:

```
for(int i = currentPermutation.size()-2; i >= 0; i--)
{
//find previous number greater than current
if(currentPermutation.get(i+1) > currentPermutation.get(i))
{
for(int j = currentPermutation.size()-2; j >= 0; j--)
{
if(currentPermutation.get(j) > currentPermutation.get(i))
{
//swap the numbers
int temp = currentPermutation.get(j);
currentPermutation.set(j, currentPermutation.get(i));
currentPermutation.set(i,temp);
//reverse the order, use sublist, then reverse
                                Collections.reverse(currentPermutation.subList(i+1, currentPermutation.size()));
break;
}
}break;
}
}
//need to reset the permutation at some point
return currentPermutation;
```

Comment: *I'm tasked with...* - so why are you asking us to do it?

Comment: Because I don't know what to do or where to go from here, I've never used ArrayLists before and was asking for help

Comment: Have you made any effort?  What have you tried? What resources have you read? If you do not understand anything then go back to your instructor to ask for more guidance.

Comment: Bro, this is my first time on here, give me a break. Yes I've tried it many times, hence why I decided to make an account and ask for help here. I've asked my instructor numerous times but have received little help at this point. I can very much share what I have done. Every Youtube video and website tells me what to do using an Array, not ArrayList

Comment: Hi @KadenJessee, as Scary Wombat said, you must read about ArrayList and List first, then try to solve the exercise. If you get stuck you can comeback here and ask a better question.

Comment: *Yes I've tried it many times* - well show us what you have tried and then maybe we can help you.

Comment: OK, next step, why do you think that this code is wrong? Does it compile? Is the output not what you think it is?  We do not have your data, so unless you spoon feed us (to some degree) it is impossible to help.

Comment: Also how is `currentPermutation` defined?

Comment: Sorry for being slow at this. Here is the feedback from my professor on what I have been needing to do:
What you are needing to do is stop both for loops after you have swapped and reversed the list, determine if you have swapped/reversed the list and then return the currentPermuation if you have or reset the permutation if no swapping/reversing was performed.

At this point I have stopped the nested for loops with those breaks, or at least I believe I have. What I don't understand is how to determine if those values have swapped and how to return the currentPermutation.

Comment: currentPermutation is defined as

private ArrayList<Integer> currentPermutation; in this same class.

Comment: Just return immediately after doing `Collections.reverse`

Comment: so I ran "return currentPermutation;" immediately after and it results in an error. The expected result is "[0,2,1]" and the actual returns as "[1,2,0]"

Comment: So this means your logic is incorrect.  I am not sure why you are using a decreasing loop, also I do not know why you need an inner loop.  I suggest that you try to debug this on paper first.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need to find next lexicographically smallest permutation.

```
Array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
Output = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
Array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1]
Output = [1,3, 5 ,1, 2, 4]
Array = [3, 2, 1]
Output = [1, 2, 3] or -1(it depends on interviewer)
```

---

[image: Here are the four step in concise way]

---

Python Code:

```
def nextPermutation(arr):
    #We will start iterating from last second element
    i = len(arr) - 2
    #Check for element index which violates monotonicity
    while i >= 0 and arr[i] >= arr[i+1]:
        i -= 1 
    if i >= 0:
        j = len(arr) - 1
        #Look for element which is just greater than arr[i]
        while arr[j] <= arr[i]:
            j -= 1
        arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i] #Swap those element
        arr[i+1::] = arr[:i:-1]#Reverse element starting from `i+1` till end
    else:
        arr[::] = arr[::-1]
```

Time Complexity - O(n)

---

Space Complexity - O(1)